# error on trying to change image in sequence from list JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list:

```
var images = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png"];
```

I made a code which attempts at displaying image1 when the page loads but for ever 3 seconds the image changes to the next image in the list. However when the code was ran it was stuck on image1 and did not change in the next 3 seconds.

This is my JavaScript code so far:

```
<html>
<body>
<body onload = "myFunction()">
<img src ="image1.png" id = "target" >
<script language="javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    var images = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png"];

function myFunction() {
   counter++;
   if (counter > 4) {
       counter = 0
   }
   target = document.getElementById ("target").src = images[counter];
   setTimeout("myFunction", 3000) 

   }
window.onLoad = function(){
myFunction(); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have seen similar codes but the answers answered did not meet my specification.

Comment: change this to `setTimeout("myFunction", 3000) ` to `setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)` and it should work you are passing string instead of function to setTimeout method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `setInterval`, you need to pass the function `myFunction` as parameter, **not** the function name `"myFunction"`:

Change it to this:

```
 setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval` (passing a function rather than a string) instead of recursively calling `setTimeout`. Also note that your `counter` logic can be greatly simplified with the use of the modulo (`%`) operator:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <img src="image1.png" alt="image1.png" id="target">
  <script language="javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    var images = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png"];
    var target = document.getElementById("target")

    setInterval(function myFunction() {
      counter = (counter + 1) % images.length
      target.src = target.alt = images[counter]
    }, 3000)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout - will work only one time
setInterval - will continue always

```
<html>
<body>
<img src ="logo.png" id = "target" >


<script language="javascript">
var counter = 0;
var images = ["logo.png", "222.jpg"];

function myFunction() {
  counter++;

  if (counter > 1) {
       counter = 0
  }
  target = document.getElementById("target").src = images[counter];
}

function my2(){
  setInterval("myFunction()", 1000);
}

window.onload = function(){
my2();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what others have mentioned already.

1. It's window.*onload* - not window.*onLoad*  - Casing is important
2. Update to

   ```
   setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
   ```
3. Place that in your window.onload

JS:

```
var counter = 0;
var images = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png"];

function myFunction() {
   counter++;
   if (counter > 4) {
       counter = 0
   }
   target = document.getElementById ("target").src = images[counter];
}

window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(myFunction, 3000) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

```
var counter = 0;
var images = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png"];
function myFunction() {
   counter++;
   if (counter > 3) {
       counter = 0
   }
   target = document.getElementById("target").src = images[counter];
}

setInterval(myFunction, 3000);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/d6tsnpxL/)